# Edit iText PDF Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've been trying to load a PDF file located at "/resources/pdf/". I want to load the pdf, fill the form fields and return a stream. This is working so far, there are no errors or exceptions.
The problem is that when the resulting PDF is printed parts of the document is missing. Using [this pdf](http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf), it is just printing the form fields, but not the images or the text. The code is running in a tomcat7 in combination with primefaces:

```
public StreamedContent modify() {
String pdfFile = "mypdf.pdf";
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    InputStream istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pdf/" + pdfFile);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(istream);

    pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bos );
    pdfForm = pdfStamper.getAcroFields();

    // fillData();

    pdfStamper.close();
    reader.close();
    istream.close();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
    return new DefaultStreamedContent( bis, "application/pdf", "report.pdf" ); 

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

I do build project this way: `mvn clean install tomcat7:redeploy -DskipTests`

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What library are you using? Where is that `StreamedContent` and `PdfReader `coming from?

Comment: sorry, library that i'm using itext 5.5

Comment: How do you build your jar? If you happen to use maven a typical error would be to have your resource folders configured for filtering.

Comment: I do build project this way: 
mvn clean install tomcat7:redeploy -DskipTests

Comment: Just is printing form fields, but not the image or text. No errors or exceptions found,document printed without images and texts. Seems like this piece of code not working properly:
InputStream istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pdf/" + pdfFile);

Comment: How do you print? From your setup I would guess from a webbrowser (PDFViewer or Adobe Reader)? If you can print something then the InputStream line you mentioned should work. Add the following line afterwards: `System.out.println(istream .available());` .

Comment: *"I do build project this way: mvn clean install"* - so you use maven. Have you checked whether resource filtering is activated in your pom file? It shouldn't be, at least not for pdfs.

Comment: @mkl I doubt that there is a problem loading the PDF. His code is working fine. However afterwards when printing the document only the formfield data is printed an not the images / pagecontent...

Comment: Lonzak System.out.println(istream.available()); throws java.io.IOException: Stream closed. 
mkl My pom file not filtering for any resource.
Lonzak You are right, the problem occurs when loading the pdf file

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I just experienced the same problem! After intensive research I detected that maven broke the encoding of my PDF files. I should have more carefully read MKLs comment ;-)

I added the resource plugin to my maven project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <!-- Please note that images like jpg, jpeg, gif, bmp and png are (already) implicitly excluded -->
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Old post:**

Your post lacks vital information:

1. How do you print your report.pdf? From the webbrowser or Adobe Reader? Please post the report.pdf so we can analyze.
2. What I understand is, that the code you posted works fine (no error, no exception). The problem occurs **only** at printing?

One shot what might be wrong:

You do not set the encoding (e.g. UTF-8) for your stream:

`return new DefaultStreamedContent( bis, "application/pdf", "report.pdf", "YourEncoding");`

and by the way the original PDF is buggy, too (E.g. Preflight reports serveral errors.)

Comment: Tried with return new DefaultStreamedContent( bis, "application/pdf", "report.pdf", "UTF8"); and UTF-8 and nothing

Comment: Hi Lonzak, sorry:

1. Webbrowser
2. Yes, only at printing

Comment: Can you open the PDF in Adobe Reader and print? Is it the same?

Comment: when i said printing, i mean print on screen, not a printer. By opening with adobe reader shows the same that with webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

I have finally decided to do it in another way.

In the project properties file I have added a new property with the path where the PDF is located, in this way I can load the pdfReader object with File through the new FileInputStream
Final code

```
public StreamedContent modify() {
    File file = getPdfFile(); 
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(file));
    pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bos );
    // fillData();
    pdfStamper.close();
    bos.close();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    return new DefaultStreamedContent( bis, "application/pdf", "report.pdf" );
}

public File getPdfFile() {
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader()
               .getResourceAsStream("myfile.properties"));
        String pdfPath = prop.getProperty("pdf.path");
        String pdfName = prop.getProperty("pdf.name");
        File file = new File(pdfPath + pdfName);

        return file;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!
Regards,

Comment: Look at my answer - the FileInputStream works since you access the file which has not been corrupted by maven. Add the plugin I wrote and you can chose your original code...